# FileNotFoundException while reading RSS in Android

Tags: android, rss, filenotfoundexception, rss-reader

I am trying to read [an RSS feed](http://screenrant.com/mobile/movie-news-feed.php). I have tried many links using the code below and succeeded, but when I try with that link above I get a FileNotFoundException. What could cause this, and how do I fix my code?

`EfficientAdapter` class:

```
package com.xmlparse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Post> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    //public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    ViewHolder holder;

    EfficientAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Post> d) {
            activity = a;
            data = d;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //      imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
            return data.toArray().length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
            public TextView label;
            public TextView addr;
            public ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.label = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    holder.addr = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.details);
                    holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
                    vi.setTag(holder);
            } else
                    holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

            holder.label.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
    //      holder.addr.setText(data.get(position).getPubDate());
            holder.addr.setText(data.get(position).getDescription());
             imageLoader.DisplayImage((data.get(position).getThumbnail()), activity,
                            holder.image, 72, 72);
             URL url = null;
             try {
                    url = new URL((data.get(position).getThumbnail()));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            InputStream content = null;
            try {
                    content = (InputStream)url.getContent();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src"); 
            Bitmap mIcon1 = null;
             try {
                     mIcon1 =
                            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mIcon1, 72, 72, false));


            return vi;
     }

}
```

`Post` class:

```
package com.xmlparse;
public class Post {

    private String title;
    private String thumbnail;
    private String url;
    private String description;
    private String pubDate;

    public String getTitle() {
            return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
    }

    public String getThumbnail() {
            return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
            this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
            return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
            return description;
    }

    public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
            this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }

    public String getPubDate() {
            return pubDate;
    }

   }
```

`xmlparsemain` activity class:

```
package com.xmlparse;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class xmlparsemain extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ListView lv1;
    ProgressDialog ShowProgress;
    public ArrayList<Post> PostList = new ArrayList<Post>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            ShowProgress = ProgressDialog.show(xmlparsemain.this, "",
                            "Loading. Please wait...", true);
            new loadingTask().execute("http://screenrant.com/mobile/movie-reviews-feed.php");

            lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri
                                            .parse(PostList.get(position).getUrl()));
                            startActivity(intent);

                    }
            });

    }

    class loadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

                    SAXHelper sh = null;
                    try {
                            sh = new SAXHelper(urls[0]);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    sh.parseContent("");
                    return "";

            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    lv1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(xmlparsemain.this, PostList));
                    ShowProgress.dismiss();

            }
    }

    class SAXHelper {
            public HashMap<String, String> userList = new HashMap<String, String>();
            private URL url2;

            public SAXHelper(String url1) throws MalformedURLException {
                    this.url2 = new URL(url1);
            }

            public RSSHandler parseContent(String parseContent) {
                    RSSHandler df = new RSSHandler();
                    try {

                            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                            xr.setContentHandler(df);

                       /*     URLConnection con = url2.openConnection();
                            con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
                         InputSource   is = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                       xr.parse(is);*/
                            xr.parse(new InputSource(url2.openStream()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return df;
            }
    }

    class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

            private Post currentPost = new Post();
            StringBuffer chars = new StringBuffer();

            @Override
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                            Attributes atts) {

                    chars = new StringBuffer();
                    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                            throws SAXException {

                    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")
                                    && currentPost.getTitle() == null) {
                            currentPost.setTitle(chars.toString());

                    }
                    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")
                                    && currentPost.getPubDate() == null) {
                            currentPost.setPubDate(chars.toString());

                    }
                    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")
                                    && currentPost.getDescription() == null) {
                            currentPost.setDescription(chars.toString());

                    }
                    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("thumbnail")
                                    && currentPost.getThumbnail() == null) {
                            currentPost.setThumbnail(chars.toString());

                    }
                    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")
                                    && currentPost.getUrl() == null) {
                            currentPost.setUrl(chars.toString());
                    }

                    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                            PostList.add(currentPost);
                            currentPost = new Post();
                    }

            }

            @Override
            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
                    chars.append(new String(ch, start, length));
            }

     }

}
```

My logcat report:

```
02-29 15:20:44.183: W/System.err(2470): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://screenrant.com/mobile/movie-news-feed.php
```

Comment: can you post the complete LogCat for the error?

Comment: it will show in logcat 02-29 14:58:51.104: E/RSSParser(2212): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://screenrant.com/mobile/movie-news-feed.php

Comment: post the whole logcat of the error if you want people to be able to help you, not just one line.  It should list all the effected lines, including the line in your code which is throwing the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using HTtpConnection instead of URLConnection, as follows:

```
InputStream callWebErvice(String serviceURL){
        // http get client
            HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet getRequest=new HttpGet();

            try {
                // construct a URI object
                getRequest.setURI(new URI(serviceURL));
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                Log.e("URISyntaxException", e.toString());
            }

            // buffer reader to read the response
            BufferedReader in=null;
            // the service response
            HttpResponse response=null;
            try {
                // execute the request
                response = client.execute(getRequest);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("IO exception", e.toString());
            }
            if(response!=null)
                return response.getEntity().getContent();
            else
                return null;

    }
```

and change line `xr.parse(new InputSource(url2.openStream()));`

to

```
xr.parse(new InputSource(callWebErvice(url2)));
```